# Cannonball Conundrum

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to, with an input number `p`, find the smallest positive cannonball number of order `p` that is NOT 1.

#### Definition

A cannonball number (of order `p`) is a number which is both:

- An `p`-gonal number ([See this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number)).
- and an `p`-gonal pyramid number.

  - The `n`th `p`-gonal pyramid number is the sum of the 1st to `n`th `p`-gonal numbers.

    - (e.g. `4th square pyramid number = 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 = 30`)
  - The picture below represents the 4th square pyramid number, as a square pyramid.
    [image]
  - For more info, visit [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number).

The cannonball number of order 3, for example, is 10, because it is:

- The fourth triangle number (`1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10`)
- and the third triangular pyramid number. (`1 + 3 + 6 = 10`)

#### Formulas

**NOTE: If you can find (or make) more useful formulae than my ones here, please post it here (or message me on the question chat thing).**

- If you're interested, the formula for the `n`th `p`-gonal number is:

[image]

- And the `n`th `p`-gonal pyramid number is:

[image]

#### Specs

- `p` is guaranteed to be larger than 2.
- The program must check values for a solution for `p` up to (and including) `2^16`. Your program may do anything if no solutions are found for `p`.
- Only positive indices for `n`.

#### Test cases

- `3` outputs `10` (4th triangle number, 3rd triangle pyramid number)
- `4` outputs `4900` (70th square number, 24th square pyramid number)

This is code-golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Note: If you do post a solution, please include a description of how the code works.

Should I start a bounty for a solution which is better and doesn't use my formulae?

Comment: Could you add some more detail about what a cannonball number is? It's not entirely clear from your description.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there is an answer for any `n`? If not, what is the range of `n` you'll be using?

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan Edited to make a definition. `n`-gonal and `n`-gonal pyramid numbers shouldn't need defining.

Comment: @Geobits Edited to make a range instead of using memory.

Comment: Ok, fair warning though: I don't think you're going to find solutions for most `n`. Even using just `n=5`, you have to go to 243M to find one (unless I plugged in the wrong formula here).

Comment: @DerpfacePython TL;DR: Cannonball numbers quite rare. Look for yourself.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ I know that I'm not guaranteed to have a number for every input. TBH, I had no idea how rare they were until you told me - I can't even find a decent page on them.

Comment: @DerpfacePython Let's delete these comments about the sandbox and stuff so a mod doesn't have to, and I would be happy to chat there.

Comment: @Geobits, There are solutions to {3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 14, 17, 23, 26, 30, 32, 35, 41, 43, 50, 88}.  I only checked to 100.

Comment: I did understand what he means. Took me a while, but I did. My PHP program has 140 bytes.

Comment: @Titus Is there any way I can improve my explanation of cannonball numbers?

Comment: Wait, how is this question unclear? It seems pretty clear that I want cannonball numbers, and I've explained in-depth what cannonball numbers are.

Comment: maybe an explanation of n-gonals an n-pyramidals (or at least links to helpful pages on them). images for n=3 and n=4 would definetely help to understand.

Comment: @Titus Chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42136/cannonball-numbers).

Comment: Can you include a formula for the i'th n-gonal triangular and pyramidal number?

Comment: @xnor Yup, got it!

Comment: If Geobits was right, then in Python it would be: `[0,0,0,10,4900]`.

Comment: not figurative enough yet? **For a given n>2 find a number x, so that you can make** a) a polygon from x dots that has n sides and b) a pyramid from x spheres based on a polygon of the same shape **for n=4:** a) x=9 can shape a 3x3 square (polygon with 4 sides) b) x=5 can build a 2x2+1x1 pyramid; it´s a 4-pyramidal (or square pyramidal) number _btw: 70*70 is the only solution for n=4_ **for n=3:** triangle numbers are [1, 1+2=3, 3+3=6, 3+4=10, ...] 3-pyramidal numbers are [1, 1+3=4, 4+6=10, ...] **x=10** can build a) a triangle of 1+2+3+4 dots and b) a triangular pyramid with 1+3+6 cannonballs

Comment: The formula for the nth p-gonal pyramid number should be ((p − 2)n³ + 3n² − (p − 5)n)/6, not ((p − 2)n³ + 3n² + (p − 5)n)/6.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Whup... thanks for catching that!

Comment: Do you consider 946 a cannonball number of order 6, since it is the 11th hexagonal pyramid number and the −22nd hexagonal number?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Yep, that would be a cannonball number. I'm pretty sure that's the smallest one as well. *NOTE: You mean 22nd not -22nd, right?*

Comment: @DerpfacePython No I do mean (−22)nd, that’s why it’s a question. You can plug in *p* = 6, *n* = −22 to the polygonal number formula and get 946. The question is whether you are including numbers with negative indices.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Ah... in that case, only positive indices are allowed (If n = 22 were plugged in, it would still return 946).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42195/discussion-between-derpfacepython-and-anders-kaseorg).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>129</s> 127 bytes

```
def f(p):
 x=2
 while 1:
  for i in range(x*x):
   if i//x*((p-2)*i//x+4-p)/2==i%x*(i%x+1)*((p-2)*i%x+5-p)/6==x:return x
  x+=1
```

A function that takes input via argument and returns the output.

This is an *extremely* naïve brute force, and takes a very long time for even moderately large `p`; the execution time will be ridiculous for anything approaching the given maximum for `p` of `2^16`, but there is no reason why the program would not work, given sufficient time.

There are probably far shorter and faster ways of doing this, but I thought it would be good to post something to get this started off.

**How it works**

The return value `x` is initialised to `2`, and then the program simply loops over all the `p`-gonal and `p`-gonal pyramidal numbers up to order `x`. If the current `p`-gonal and `p`-gonal pyramidal numbers, calculated using the formulas, are equal to each other and to `x`, then `x` must be the relevant cannonball number and this is returned. Else, `x` is incremented, and the program tries again for the new value of `x`.

In terms of golfing, a Cartesian product is used to collapse the two for-loops for the `p`-gonal and `p`-gonal pyramidal numbers into a single loop, and the formulas were factorised further to save a few bytes.

Comment: Ummm... this might be a bit too late to say... but... my formula was wrong. You just need to change the polygonal formula.

Comment: @DerpfacePython Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>111</s> 98 bytes

```
f=n=>{for(b=c=g=1;b++;)for(p=b*(b*3+b*b*(n-2)-n+5)/6;g<p;c++)if(p==(g=c*(c*n-c-c-n+4)/2))return p}
```

**ungolfed**

```
f=n=>{
for(b=2,c=g=1;b<1e6;b++)    // run index b from 2 (to 100k)
    for(
        p=(b*b*3+b*b*b*(n-2)-b*(n-5))/6 // p=the b-th n-pyramidal number
        ;g<p&&c<1e6;c++)   // run while n-gonal is lower than n-pyramidal (and c below 100k)
        if(p==(
            g=(c*c*(n-2)-c*(n-4))/2     // g=the c-th n-gonal number
        )) return p                     // if they are equal, return
}
```

c is not reinitialized in the inner loop because the next p[b] is definitely larger than the current g[c] (so we have to move *on* anyway)

**examples**

```
samples=[3,4,6,8,10,11,14,17,23,26,30,32,35,41,43,50,88]
for(i in samples) document.write('n='+(n=samples[i])+': '+f(n)+'<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

## old PHP program, <s>115</s> 106 bytes

<sup>+16 for current PHP, see below</sup>

```
<?for($b=2;1;$b++)for($p=$b*($b*3+$b*$b*($n-2)-$n+5)/6;$g<$p;++$c)if($p==$g=$c*($c*$n-2*$c-$n+4)/2)echo$p;
```

- loops forever
- usage: with PHP<4.2: run from browser with `<scriptpath>?n=<number>`
  with PHP<5.4, add `register_globals=1` to `php.ini` (+18 ?)
- see [my JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/cannonball-conundrum/85142#85142) for description
- +10 for PHP>=5.4: replace `1` with `$n=$_GET[n]`. Or replace `1` with `$n=$argv[1]`, run `php -f <filename> <number>`.
- +6 for finite loop on success: replace `echo$p` with `die(print$p)`
- +/- 0 for function:

  ```
  function f($n){for($b=2;1;$b++)for($p=$b*($b*3+$b*$b*($n-2)-$n+5)/6;$g<$p;++$c)if($p==$g=$c*($c*$n-2*$c-$n+4)/2)return$p;}
  ```

  loops forever if it finds nothing. Replace `1` with `$p<1e6` to break at 100k or with `$p<$p+1` to loop until integer overflow. (tested with PHP 5.6)

**examples** (on function)

```
$samples=[3,4,6,8,10,11,14,17,23,26,30,32,35,41,43,50,88];
foreach($samples as $n)echo "<br>n=$n: ", f($n);
```

**examples output**

```
n=3: 10
n=4: 4900
n=6: 946
n=8: 1045
n=10: 175
n=11: 23725
n=14: 441
n=17: 975061
n=23: 10680265
n=26: 27453385
n=30: 23001
n=32: 132361021
n=35: 258815701
n=41: 55202400
n=43: 245905
n=50: 314755
n=88: 48280
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 107 bytes

```
#define X(x)(1+p/2.0*x)*++x
c(p,m,n,a,b){m=n=a=b=1;p-=2;do if(a>b)b+=X(n);else a=X(m);while(a^b);return a;}
```

Ungolfed with test parameters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define X(x)(1+p/2.0*x)*++x
int c(int p)
{
    int m = 1, n = 1, a = 1, b = 1;
    p -= 2;
    do
        if(b < X(m))
            b += X(n);
        else
            a = X(m);
    while(a != b);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", c(3));
    printf("%d\n", c(4));
}
```

This uses the fact that the n-th p-gonal number can be defined as `n(1+(p-2)(n-1)/2)` and the pyramid number is the sum of the aforementioned numbers.

I think it can be further golfed, given that it's not really necessary for variable `a` to be saved.

Comment: Wait... is the `i` in your formula the imaginary number `i`?

Comment: Oops, sorry. `i` is supposed to be `n`. I had different notation littered in my research. I can't imagine using an imaginary number for this problem, and I definitely can't imagine using it in C.